# Image Filter in ng-grid using angular Js is not properly working

Tags: angularjs, filter, ng-grid

I want to display images based on the value ,so I tried applying some filter for it ,but cant figure out why it is not working.It is just displaying a column with no image at all.Dont know what is going wrong,why it is not taking proper matching.Please some help me out.Thanks in advance.Any help will be appreciated.

My filter looks like

```
app .filter('imagefilter', function() {
    return function(SA) { 
      if('SA'===0) return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA';
      if('SA'===1) return 'http://goo.gl/vxCnLC';
      if('SA'===2) return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA';
        //other mappings
   }
});
```

And cell template looks like

```
{
      field: "SA",
      sortable:true,
      displayName:"Service Affecting",
     cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text><img class="flag" ng-src="{{row.getProperty(\'SA\') | imagefilter}}"</img></span></div>',
    width: '80px'

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if("SA"==="0") return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA';
```

will never be true, I think you want

```
if(SA==="0") return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA';
```

Comment: I would like to get attention toward the thing that i am getting my data from some external JSON file

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've got the following grid to work, its a little simplified from the one in the original post:

The filter:

```
.filter('imagefilter', function() {
        return function(SA) {
            if(SA==='0') { return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA'; }
            if(SA==='1') { return 'http://goo.gl/vxCnLC'; }
            if(SA==='2') { return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA'; }
            return 'unknown';
        };

    })
```

The grid:

```
<div class='gridStyle' ng-grid='gridOptions'></div>
```

Some sample data:

```
$scope.myData = [{name:'John', SA:'0'}, 
                 {name:'Mary', SA: '1'}, 
                 {name:'Fred', SA: '2'}, 
                 {name:'Joan', SA: '0'}];
```

The grid template:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', 
columnDefs:[{field:'name', displayName:'Name'}, 
            {field:'SA', displayName:'ServiceAffecting', 
cellTemplate:'<div><img ng-src="{{row.getProperty(\'SA\') | imagefilter}}"></img></div>'}]};
```

The error in your template was not surrounding row.getProperty with {{}} probably quite hard to spot given the complexity of the template.

Comment: It doesnot work in my case ,may be because i am taking data to be filled into the grid from some JSON file...http://plnkr.co/edit/7NkYmP0EMUS0agGZbWve?p=preview, check and suggest me what i am doing wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Your plunkr has a couple of problems: see answer below

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems in the plnkr you posted:

1. Your filter is still doing the following;

   if('SA'===0) { return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA'; }

it needs to remove the single quotes from SA

```
if(SA===0) { return 'http://goo.gl/aFomAA'; }
```

2. The filter needs to be moved above this line of code

   $scope.filter = 'D';

I don't know why but $scope.filter seems to interfere with app.filter - I don't follow what this section of code is doing, but moving the filter above this line works.

3. There are extra double quotes in the cell template

   cellTemplate:''

it should be:

```
cellTemplate:'<div><img ng-src="{{row.getProperty(\'SA\') | imagefilter}}"></img></div>'
```

With these 3 changes the filter seems to work properly except that one of the items is SA=4 which isn't in the filter yet.

I forked and updated your plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/oaFjjBMVa632NbEHSjGR?p=preview

Comment: I have tried using quotation,removing them and ya that $scope.filter='D' is just unneccesary ,removed it.After making changes that you suggested my grid is just showing an empty column with no images at all ...thats the real problem ,somehow it is not taking the values from JSON I think :( or dont know but m unable to find out whats wrong with it.Also the link that u shared is not updated,,,if u have made changes to my plunker and if its displaying images,then please share that link too

Comment: plnkr seems to be down so I can't verify my link just yet.  In the meantime try and remove the image and remove the filter: <div>{{row.getProperty(\'SA\')}}</div>.  If that works then add in the filter <div>{{row.getProperty(\'SA\') | imagefilter}}</div>. if that works then try and reinstate the img tag. The first step will verify that your json is being handled correctly.  The second step will verify the operation of your filter.

Comment: problem is with imagefilter only :(

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oaFjjBMVa632NbEHSjGR?p=preview has been updated - can you check again?